# Nullable Int comparison in Linq Expression Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that is returning 0 results when the database has valid entries. I think this is down to a nullable foreign key on the comparison.

I have;

```
return context.Where<Job>(
       x =>
       x.StatusId != completeStatus.Id &&
       x.StatusId != cancelledStatus.Id).ToList();
```

where StatusId is;

```
[ForeignKey("Status")]
public int? StatusId { get; set; }
```

I want to include all jobs where the StatusId is either null or not the value of the 2 Ids (arbitary integers).

How can I correct the above statement to return results please?

Comment: Well have you tried using `x.StatusId == null || (/* existing condition here */)`? That's what you *described*...

Comment: That's because in SQL you (in most cases) cannot compare value with null using `=` or `!=` - both `null = something` and `null != something` will return false. You need to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`, and that's to what `x.Something != null` will be translated to (while `x.Something != variable` will be translated to `Something != @variable`).

Comment: The full linq query has additional date field checks that involves returning jobs between a certain date as well. It seems to be a combination of the two ad the OR does fix it (albeit only without the date check).

    return context.Where<Job>(
           x =>
           x.NextDueDate != null &&
           x.NextDueDate >= from &&
           x.NextDueDate <= to &&
           (x.StatusId == null ||
           (x.StatusId != completeStatus.Id &&
            x.StatusId != cancelledStatus.Id))).ToList();

Comment: I apologise as I did try this but splitting and thought the issue remained with the nullable int check, however, it seems to be when the two are combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (if it is LINQ to Entities because it handles comparison to nullables in a somewhat SQL like way)

```
!x.StatusId.HasValue
|| (x.StatusId!= completeStatus.Id
  && x.StatusId != cancelledStatus.Id)
```

With other LINQ providers you may need to use `x.StatusId.Value` in the value comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `OR` for the StatusId  is `null`

```
return context.Where<Job>(
   x =>
   (x.StatusId != completeStatus.Id &&
   x.StatusId != cancelledStatus.Id) ||
   x.StatusId == null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you want something like this:

```
return context.Where<Job>(
       x =>
       !x.HasValue ||
       (x.StatusId.Value != completeStatus.Id &&
       x.StatusId.Value != cancelledStatus.Id)).ToList();
```

It's important to remember that an `int?` isn't a base type and does not in any way inherit from `int`/`Int32`.  It's just syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`. It's an `object` with a `Value` property that may be null.  This is true of any `Nullable<T>`.

It's also important to implement parentheses to separate your comparisons to prevent unpredictable results and make code maintenance easier.  Here, it makes it clear that we want all results that are *either* without a value for *x*, or those whose value exists and both doesn't match `completeStatus.Id` and `cancelledStatus.Id`.